# postgresql libpqxx Several queries as one transaction

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

Is it possible to execute one transaction contains several queries, for example insert smth in table1 and insert smth in table2? How I can implement this? I use `libpqxx` to interact the database and expect an answer relating to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pqxx::work`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00205.html#ga82685329d6fd91f5ab30772d266fe5f0) is a default transaction type.
Use multiple `exec()` method before `commit()` to run multiple queries in one transaction:

```
using namespace pqxx;
...
  connection c("dbname=test user=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1");
  work w(c);
  w.exec("create table test_xx (id int primary key)");
  w.exec("insert into test_xx values (1)");
  w.commit();
...
```