# postgresql libpqxx: Several queries as one transaction

Tags: postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

When inserting/updating data in postgresql, it is easy to [execute multiple statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461366/postgresql-libpqxx-several-queries-as-one-transaction) in one transaction.  (My goal here is to avoid a server round-trip for each statement, although the transactional isolation is often useful.)

When querying, I'm unclear if this is possible.  I'd somehow need to know what function is going to consume each bit and how to separate the bits.

```
connection c("dbname=test user=postgres hostaddr=127.0.0.1");
work w(c);
w.exec("SELECT a, b FROM my_table WHERE c = 3;");
w.exec("SELECT x, y, z FROM my_other_table WHERE c = 'dog';");
w.commit();
```

Assume I've got functions `my_parse_function()` and `my_other_parse_function()` that can read rows from each of these queries, were I doing them separately.

Comment: Do you want that both query executed on same state of database?

Comment: Yes, sorry: I have a context where I'll do a few dozen different SELECTs in a row before embarking on a computation.  The question is whether I can do that without a few dozen round trips to the db.

Comment: Try this. The SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT command allows a new transaction to run with the same snapshot as an existing transaction.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid round trips, transactions don't help.

Transaction isolation in Postgres (as with most RDBMSs) doesn't rely on the server executing all of your statements at once. Each statement in your transaction will be sent and executed at the point of the `exec()` call; isolation is provided by the engine's [concurrency control model](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html), allowing multiple clients to issue commands simultaneously, and presenting each with a different view of the database state.

If anything, wrapping a sequence of statements in a transaction will add *more* communication overhead, as additional round-trips are required to issue the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` commands.

---

If you want to issue several *commands* in one round-trip, you can do so by calling `exec()` with a single semicolon-separated multi-statement string. These statements will be implicitly treated as a single transaction, provided that there is no explicit transaction already active, and that the string doesn't include any explicit `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands.

If you want to send multiple *queries*, the [protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#id-1.10.5.7.4) does allow for multiple result sets to be returned in response to a multi-query string, but `exec()` doesn't give you access to them; it's just a [wrapper](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/blob/ce782652ef467c350189022c80df495b7aa958f7/src/connection.cxx#L567) for `libpq`'s [`PQexec()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQEXEC), which discards all but the last result.

Instead, you can use a [`pipeline`](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/a01041.html), which lets you issue asynchronous queries via `insert()`, and then `retrieve()` the results at your leisure (blocking until they arrive, if necessary). Setting a `retain()` limit will allow the pipeline to accumulate statements, and then send them together as a multi-command string.